# Limit of composition of function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0  & \text{ if } x= 1/n\\  \sin x & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$  $$g(x)=\begin{cases}0  & \text{ if } x= 0\\  \dfrac{\sin x}{x} & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$ then$$( g\circ f)=?$$$$\lim _{x \to 0 }(g\circ f )=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$My Attempt:\\
(g\circ f)(x)=\begin{cases}0
 & \text{ if } x= 0\\ 
\frac{sinf(x)}{f(x)} & \text{ if }  x=1/n
\\ 
\frac{sinx(sinx)}{sinx}& \text{} otherwise
\end{cases}\\ \lim _{x \to 0 }(g\circ f)(x)=1 \\\text{Is it ok or something went wrong.} $

Comment: For $x=\frac 1 n$ the value of $g(f(x))$ is $0$ because $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I'd suggest including your attempt in the body of the question so others can see it.

Comment: Ok next tym i will

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)=0$ only when $x=1/n$ or $x=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $f(x)\ne 0$ for other values of $x$. Thus,
$$\left(g\circ f\right)(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x=1/n\text{ or } x=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z} \\
\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{\sin x} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$ 
We have that $\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{\sin x}\to 1$ as $x\to 0$. However, in any right neighborhood of $0$, there are values of $x$ ($x=1/n$ for a sufficiently large $n$) for which $\left(g\circ f\right)(x)=0$. This means that $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(g\circ f\right)(x)$ doesn't exist.

It's also important to realize that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ together with $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=1$ do not allow us to conclude about the limit of the composition because the required [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions) for this theorem are not fulfilled.